# NFC reading Android Java - null object from getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm trying to realize a simple Android application to read from an NFC tag.
I followed the official documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc) to actually realize an application that is almost equal to the one created by "codexpedia" -> [Source code](https://github.com/codexpedia/android_nfc_read_write).

When a tag is near the smartphone the onNewIntent method is call, but, when I try to get data through the method `getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)`, I always obtain null.

You can find the code that is causing the problem at the following direct link [link](https://github.com/codexpedia/android_nfc_read_write/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/peng/nfcreadwrite/MainActivity.java)

Is there anyone that knows why it happens?

Comment: Does the Tag have an Ndef message on it? Use an App like NFC tools or NXP Taginfo App to check what is on the Tag. If there is no Ndef message on the Tag then that method will return null. As the code linked is set to detect Tags without Ndef messages on them with the `ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED` and then assumes that they are Ndef capable (so a bug in that code)

Comment: If I try to read a tag from another app on the PlayStore (NFC Writer) I see the following: `Technologies: NfcV, NdefFormatable DSF ID 0`, `Response Flag 0`, `Max Transceive Length 253 bytes`. I assume it actually says that it contains an Ndef message?

Answer (score 1):

`NdefFormatable` technology means the card is capable of storing a Ndef message once it has been formatted.

So basically there is no Ndef message on this card, once it has been formatted and a Ndef message put on it then the code will be able to read this card.

You can use Apps like NFC tools or NXP TagWriter App to Format and add an Ndef message

Once formatted it should show the `NfcV, Ndef` technologies.

The bug in the code https://github.com/codexpedia/android_nfc_read_write/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/peng/nfcreadwrite/MainActivity.java

Line 80 - `IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);`

Should be
`IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);`

As it assumes that all cards have a Ndef message to read from, this is not the case for unformatted cards, bank cards, A lot of Transport cards, etc

Also line 91 to 93 - `if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {`

Should be
`if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {`

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. A further question: may I ask you to also suggest changes to do (or a link to a "simple" ready project or a link to the documentation) that can help me in understanding how to do it in order to read every kind of format?
Thank you again for your very useful support

Comment: I have already suggested changes to do to fix the bug in the codexpedia example, so it only tries to read Ndef messages from cards with Ndef messages on them. There are too many other data formats like Ndef to document. Low level card type like NfcV is documented at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/package-summary . You can usually also gain understanding to the low level card type access from the datasheet of the card you are trying to read but as you don't specify the make and model of the card I cannot point you to that.